# Static IP Option in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Order IP Address using SL java API.
After the option for static IP has been chosen, subnet and IP information are listed to assign ordered IPs. Please check the image I've captured.

What java api can i use to get the subnet, Vlan, and Type information ?

[image: Static IP Options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SoftLayer_Account::getSubnets](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getSubnets) with object masks and filters.
Below is a REST example can help you to get the same list of SL Portal:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getSubnets?objectMask=mask[id,addressSpace,networkIdentifier,totalIpAddresses,version,networkVlan[id,vlanNumber,primaryRouter[id,hostname]],cidr,routingTypeKeyName]&objectFilter={   "subnets": {     "addressSpace": {       "operation": "PUBLIC"     },     "version": {       "operation": 4     }   } }

Method: GET
```

Note:  the `object filters` are not implemented for Java client, please use other way to filter the Subnet list.